# Why is my class not responding to this CSS class?

Tags: html, css, computer-science

I've been linked a stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../www.assistans.tv/css/joncss.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The css is:

```
.meravsnitt {
        font-color: #FFF;
        }
```

and the html class is:

```
<span class="meravsnitt">Se fler avsnitt</span>
```

- I am new to CSS and HTML i am working on this website right now: 
  http://109.74.0.128/~app/assistanstv/assistanstv/www.assistans.tv/index.html

Comment: Change `font-color` to `color`

Answer (score 3):

change css property name `font-color` to `color`

```
.meravsnitt {
        color: #FFF;
        }

.play_videolist-section-header__icon::before{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how to make this arrow white? http://prntscr.com/eqop5o